# Creating a calendar with JSandHtml

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted my code to display the calendar after prompting the user to place an input
the output should be numbers corresponding to month and days corresponding to Monday to Sunday.
I was not able to find out what I am lacking with also am I am still yet to compose a css file
is this the reason why It won't show anything on browser / live server in visual studio code? Please help me

This is my html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="em">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Git Demonstration</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="js/my.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my java script code:

```js
var inpMonth, inpDay;
    inpMonth = prompt("Month 1-12")
    inpDay = prompt("Start Day 1-7")

    function Calendar(element, month, day) {
        const days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
        let mName = ''
        if (month == 1)
            mName = 'JANUARY'
        else if (month == 2)
            mName = 'FEBRUARY'
        else if (month == 3)
            mName = 'MARCH'
        else if (month == 4)
            mName = 'APRIL'
        else if (month == 5)
            mName = 'MAY'
        else if (month == 6)
            mName = 'JUNE'
        else if (month == 7)
            mName = 'JULY'
        else if (month == 8)
            mName = 'AUGUST'
        else if (month == 9)
            mName = 'SEPTEMBER'
        else if (month == 10)
            mName = 'OCTOBER'
        else if (month == 11)
            mName = 'NOVEMBER'
        else if (month == 12)
            mName = 'DECEMBER'
        else 
        {
            mName = "Invalid Input"
        }
        let WeekC = 0
        let CDays = 1
        let Adder = 1
        let tblCreate = 
        `<table>
            <tr>
            <td colspan = "7"id="month" style="text-align:center; font-size: larger;">
            ${mName}
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="color:white; background-color: black; text-align:center;">
                SUN
                </th>
                <th style="text-align:center">
                MON
                </th>
                <th style="color:white; background-color: black; text-align:center">
                TUE
                </th>
                <th style="text-align:center">
                WED
                </th>
                <th style="color:white; background-color: black; text-align:center">
                THU
                </th>
                <th style="text-align:center">
                FRI
                </th>
                <th style="color:white; background-color: black; text-align:center">
                SAT
                </th>
            </tr>`
    
    if(month > 12 || day > 7)
    {
        element.innerHTML = ('<h3 style="text-align: center; color: red; background-color:black;">Invalid Input!</h3>')
    }
    else if(month == 0 || day == 0)
        element.innerHTML = ('<h3 style="text-align: center; color: red; background-color:black;">Invalid Input!</h3>')
        else
        {
            if(days[month-1] == 31)
            {
                if(day >= 6)
                {
                    for (let i = 0; i < 42; i++) 
                    {
                        if (WeekC == 0) 
                        {
                            tblCreate  += '<tr>'
                        }
                        if (Adder <= day - 1)
                        {
                            tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                            Adder++
                        }
                        else if (CDays > days[month - 1])
                            tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
    
                        else 
                        {
                            if (CDays <= days[month - 1]) 
                            {
                                tblCreate  += `<td>${CDays}</td>`
                                CDays++
                            }
                            else
                                tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                        }
                        if (WeekC == 6) 
                        {
                            tblCreate  += '</tr>'
                            WeekC = 0
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            WeekC++
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    for (let i = 0; i < 35; i++) 
                    {
                        if (WeekC == 0)
                        {
                            tblCreate  += '<tr>'
                        }
            
                        if (Adder <= day - 1) 
                        {
                            tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                            Adder++
                        }
                            else if (CDays > days[month - 1])
                            tblCreate  += "<td></td>"

                        else 
                        {
                            if (CDays <= days[month - 1]) 
                            {
                                tblCreate  += `<td>${CDays}</td>`
                                CDays++
                            }
                            else
                                tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                        }
                        if (WeekC == 6)
                        {
                            tblCreate  += '</tr>'
                            WeekC = 0
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            WeekC++
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
            else if(days[month-1] == 28)
            {
                if(day >= 6)
                {
                    for (let i = 0; i < 35; i++) 
                    {
                        if (WeekC == 0)
                        {
                            tblCreate  += '<tr>'
                        }
                        if (adder <= day - 1) 
                        {
                            tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                            Adder++
                        }
                        else if (CDays > days[month - 1])
                            tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                        else 
                        {
                            if (CDays <= days[month - 1]) 
                            {
                                tblCreate  += `<td>${CDays}</td>`
                                CDays++
                            }
                            else
                                tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                        }
                        if (WeekC == 6) 
                        {
                            tblCreate  += '</tr>'
                            WeekC = 0
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            WeekC++
                        }
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    for (let i = 0; i < 28; i++)
                    {
                        if (WeekC == 0) 
                        {
                            tblCreate  += '<tr>'
                        }
                        if (Adder <= day - 1) 
                        {
                            tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                            Adder++
                        }
                        else if (CDays > days[month - 1])
                            tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                        else 
                        {
                            if (CDays <= days[month - 1]) 
                            {
                                tblCreate  += `<td>${CDays}</td>`
                                CDays++
                            }
                            else
                                tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                        }
                        if (WeekC == 6) 
                        {
                            tblCreate  += '</tr>'
                            WeekC = 0
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            WeekC++
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                if(day >= 6){
                    for (let i = 0; i < 35; i++) 
                    {
                        if (WeekC == 0) 
                        {
                            tblCreate  += '<tr>'
                        }
                        if (Adder <= day - 1) 
                        {
                            tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                            Adder++
                        }
                        else if (CDays > days[month - 1])
                            tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                        else 
                        {
                            if (CDays <= days[month - 1]) 
                            {
                                tblCreate  += `<td>${CDays}</td>`
                                CDays++
                            }
                            else
                                tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                        }
                        if (WeekC == 6) 
                        {
                            tblCreate  += '</tr>'
                            WeekC = 0
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            WeekC++
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (let i = 0; i < 35; i++)
                    {
                        if (WeekC == 0) 
                        {
                            tblCreate  += '<tr>'
                        }
                        if (Adder <= day - 1) 
                        {
                            tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                            Adder++
                        }
                        else if (CDays > days[month - 1])
                            tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                        else 
                        {
                            if (CDays <= days[month - 1]) 
                            {
                                tblCreate  += `<td>${CDays}</td>`
                                CDays++
                            }
                            else
                                tblCreate  += "<td></td>"
                        }
                
                        if (WeekC == 6) 
                        {
                            tblCreate  += '</tr>'
                            WeekC = 0
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            WeekC++
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            tblCreate  += '</table>'
            element.innerHTML = tblCreate ;
            }
        }

    Calendar(Cal, inpMonth, inpDay)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are missing html element in your html code and link to it in javascript.

Add element to your html code like so.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="em">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Git Demonstration</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="calendar-element"></div>
    <script src="js/my.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And add your element link variable.

```
var inpMonth, inpDay, calendarElement;
inpMonth = prompt("Month 1-12")
inpDay = prompt("Start Day 1-7")
calendarElement = document.getElementById('calendar-element')

/* here is your function */

Calendar(calendarElement, inpMonth, inpDay)
```